# QuickSort in Python - program hangs for larger input sizes?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Pretty confused about this because I've verified correct logical output for small enough testcases (N = 20). I try doing N = 10,000 numbers and the program just hangs and I don't understand why... I've implemented the algorithm as simply as I can.

Also, calling `sorted(data)` on my N = 10k list seems to work almost instantly. So I'm convinced my algorithm just gets stuck somewhere.

Here is the code:

```
def QuickSort(array):
    qsort(array, 0, len(array))


def qsort(arr, left, right):
    if ((right - left) < 2):
        return

    pivotIndex = choosePivot0(arr, left, right)

    newPivotIndex = partition(arr, pivotIndex, left, right)

    qsort(arr, 0, newPivotIndex)
    qsort(arr, newPivotIndex + 1, right)

def partition(arr, pivotIndex, left, right):
    swap(arr, pivotIndex, left)
    pivot = arr[left]
    i = left + 1
    for j in range(left+1, right):
        if (arr[j] < pivot):
            swap(arr, i, j)
            i = i + 1

    swap(arr, left, i-1) #put pivot back where it belongs
    #cobj.count = cobj.count + (right - left - 1) #add m-1 the #of comparisons
    return (i-1) #give back where the pivot resides



def swap(array, i, j):
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp

def choosePivot0(array, left, right):
    return randint(left, right-1) #random
```

So I'm pretty lost as to why this could be happening. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How long your code took to sort a 10k data? I implemented a much simple qsort, and `sys.setrecursionlimit(2**30)`, it takes about 20~30 seconds to sort `[2, 3, 5] * 10000`, a 30k data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the following line:

```
qsort(arr, 0, newPivotIndex)
```

I think it should be like this.

```
qsort(arr, left, newPivotIndex)
```

Otherwise the function will work somehow only for some of the input data sets. That is why the algorithm gets stuck.

Comment: You are my favorite person right now. Thanks a bunch, this fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I haven't check your algorithm so there maybe be a problem with it / python may not like it for some reason but:
Quick sort will approximately improve sorting time from N^2 to N log(N), but maybe as bad as N^2 depending on input data.  With optimal data, N=10,000 compared to N=20, would be a factor of 40,000/26 = 1538 times slower.  Perhaps it's just processing?

With worst case data it will be 100,000,000 / 400 = 25,000 times slower.  What's your data?

Comment: Only once in a blue moon would I expect N^2 running time complexity from QuickSort using a random pivot. Data is just a generic list of the integers 1 to 10000 in unsorted order.

Comment: Just asking incase you weren't supplying it with rnd data.

Answer (score 2):

Python often hangs for deep recursive functions, sometimes it just terminates the current session (if you are trying it out in IDLE), and starts a fresh session without giving any output at all. Try this: `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(2**30)`, this may help, though not always.